# Function to convert function to list in CLOS. Is it possible?

Tags: reflection, common-lisp, metaprogramming, clos, meta-object-protocol

Is that possible to convert code to a list in CLOS? That is; is it possible to build a function that takes an argument f, which should be a  function or method, and converts it to a List?

The goal would be to visit the list elements in the same way the Design Pattern Visitor is used to visit the nodes of the Abstract Syntax Tree of a function during compilation.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. Can you provide an example of some input and output you might want? Do you want to get the Lisp code of a function? What should happen if the function is implemented in C or assembly? There are ways to do visitor pattern like things with CLOS but that doesn’t seem to be what you are asking.

Comment: @dan-robertson, suppose function hello-word is defined as
   `(defun hello-world () (format t "hello, world"))`
Function getCode returns a list that is the source code of
its parameter, which should be a function. Assume that 
variable hw refer to hello-world. Then 
    `(getCode hw)`
would return the list  
 `(defun hello-world () (format t "hello, world"))`

Comment: what does `(get-code (lambda (x) (+ x 1)))` return? How about `(let* ((y 3) (z (compile (lambda (x) (+ x y)))) (get-code z))`? What about `(get-code #'car)`?

Comment: @dan-robertson,  <code>(get-code (lambda (x) (+ x 1)))</code>
should return <code>`(lambda (x) (+ x 1))</code>. Expression
<code>(let* ((y 3) (z (compile (lambda (x) (+ x y)))) (get-code z))</code>  should return <code>`(lambda (x) (+ x y))</code>. And 
<code>(get-code #'car)</code> should issue an error since car is not implemented in Lisp.

Comment: Lisp implementations don’t necessarily keep the code for a function around, even if they need to inline it so such a method does not exist, and even if it did it might be macroecpanded and missing environments. One can `DESCRIBE` or `DISASSEMBLE` to print compiled code. I think there’s some MOP stuff about keeping close for methods around for method combinations. Look at AMOP? If you only want code from certain functions use a custom macro instead of `defun`.

Comment: @dan-robertson, the previous comment is not well formatted. I hope this is.  `(get-code (lambda (x) (+ x 1)))`
should return `'(lambda (x) (+ x 1))`. I had to use ' instead of backquote because of the editor. Expression
`(let* ((y 3) (z (compile (lambda (x) (+ x y)))) (get-code z))`  should return `'(lambda (x) (+ x y))`. And 
(get-code #'car) should issue an error since car is not implemented in Lisp.

Comment: @dan-robertson, I looked at the "Art of Metaobject Protocol" (AMOP, I suppose) but I did not find the answer. The solution would be to use a custom macro instead of defun to keep the function code somewhere. Thanks very much for your reply.